# Sql: Calc average times a customers ordered a product in a period

Tags: sql, static, average

How would you calc how many times a product is sold in average in a week or month, year.

I'm not interested in the Amount, but how many times a customer has bought a given product.

OrderLine

```
 OrderNo | ProductNo | Amount |
----------------------------------------
       1 |         1 |     10 |
       1 |         4 |      2 |
       2 |         1 |      2 |
       3 |         1 |      4 |
```

Order

```
     OrderNo | OrderDate
  ----------------------------------------
           1 | 2012-02-21
           2 | 2012-02-22
           3 | 2012-02-25
```

This is the output I'm looking for

```
ProductNo | Average Orders a Week | Average Orders a month |
------------------------------------------------------------
        1 |                     3 |                     12 |
        2 |                     5 |                     20 |
```

Comment: How did you get the output values from the input?

Comment: Sorry, should have made it more clear, its just random data

Comment: Which SQL... SQLServer, MySQL ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a copy of DRapp's answer, but coded for SQL Server (it's too big for a comment!)

```
SELECT PreCount.ProductNo,
       PreCount.TotalCount / PreCount.CountOfYrWeeks AS AvgPerWeek,
       PreCount.TotalCount / PreCount.CountOfYrMonths AS AvgPerMonth,
       PreCount.TotalCount / PreCount.CountOfYears AS AvgPerYear
FROM   (SELECT OL.ProductNo,
               Count(*) TotalCount,
               Count(DISTINCT Datepart(wk, O.OrderDate)) AS CountOfYrWeeks,
               Count(DISTINCT Datepart(mm, O.OrderDate)) AS CountOfYrMonths,
               Count(DISTINCT Year(O.OrderDate)) AS CountOfYears
        FROM   OrderLine OL  JOIN [Order] O
                 ON OL.OrderNo = O.OrderNo
        GROUP  BY OL.ProductNo) PreCount
```

Answer (score 3):

You would have to first pre-query it grouped and counted per averaging method you wanted.  To distinguish between year 1 and 2, I would add year() of the transaction into the grouping qualifier for distinctness.  Such as Sales in Jan 2010 vs Sales in 2011 vs 2012... similarly, week 1 of 2010, week 1 of 2011 and 2012 instead of counting as all 3 years as a single week.

The following could be done if you are using MySQL

```
select
      PreCount.ProductNo,
      PreCount.TotalCount / PreCount.CountOfYrWeeks as AvgPerWeek,
      PreCount.TotalCount / PreCount.CountOfYrMonths as AvgPerMonth,
      PreCount.TotalCount / PreCount.CountOfYears as AvgPerYear
   from
      ( select
              OL.ProductNo,
              count(*) TotalCount,
              count( distinct YEARWEEK( O.OrderDate ) ) as CountOfYrWeeks,
              count( distinct Date_Format( O.OrderDate, "%Y%M" )) as CountOfYrMonths,
              count( distinct Year( O.OrderDate )) as CountOfYears
           from
              OrderLine OL
                 JOIN Order O
                    on OL.OrderNo = O.OrderNo
           group by
              OL.ProductNo ) PreCount
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have to accept Bridge's answer since I'm using Sql Server.